# Shared memory program not synchronized - Giving segmentation faults

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I am trying to use shared memory with 2 programs which I have shown here. a and b are integer arrays and array1 and array2 are arrays of strings. This is the snippet first program which loads the data in the memory

```
int size = (NUMBER_OF_DATA*(sizeof(int)+sizeof(float)));
key_t key1, key2, key3;
key1 = ftok("/home/an/Desktop/newww.c", 4);
key2 = ftok("/home/an/Desktop/part1.c", 5);
key3 = ftok("/home/an/Desktop/part2.c", 6);
int shmid = shmget(key1, size, 0777|IPC_CREAT);
int shmid1 = shmget(key2, 20*NUMBER_OF_DATA, 0777|IPC_CREAT);
int shmid2 = shmget(key3, 20*NUMBER_OF_DATA, 0777|IPC_CREAT);
int *a = (int *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
float *b = (float *)(a + NUMBER_OF_DATA);
char **array1 = (char **)shmat(shmid1, 0, 0);
printf("array1 %p\n", &array1);
char *mempos = (char *)(array1 + NUMBER_OF_DATA); 
printf("MEMPOS %p\n", &mempos);
char **array2 = (char **)shmat(shmid2, 0, 0);
char *mempos1 = (char *)(array2 + (NUMBER_OF_DATA)); 

for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_DATA; i++)
{
    a[i] = a[i];
    b[i] = b[i];
    array1[i] = mempos; 
    strcpy(array1[i], array1[i]);
    mempos += 20;
    array2[i] = mempos1;
    strcpy(array2[i], array2[i]);
    mempos1 += 20;
    printf("%p  %p  %p  %p\n", &a[i], &b[i], array1[i], array2[i]);
}

j = 0;
while (j<5)
{
    j++;
    for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_DATA; i++)
    {
        printf("%s  %s  %d  %f\n", array1[i], array2[i], a[i], b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    sleep(2);
}
```

I am trying to load some data in the shared memory by the above file and alter the elements in the shared memory by the file below. But as soon as I update a string in the file below, I get garbage values from the program above instead of the altered values. I am totally confused. Have tried debugging with gdb but everything looks okay there.

```
int size = (NUMBER_OF_DATA*(sizeof(int)+sizeof(float))) + (2*(20*NUMBER_OF_DATA));
key_t key1, key2, key3;
key1 = ftok("/home/an/Desktop/newww.c", 4);
key2 = ftok("/home/an/Desktop/part1.c", 5);
key3 = ftok("/home/an/Desktop/part2.c", 6);
int shmid = shmget(key1, size, 0777|IPC_CREAT);
int shmid1 = shmget(key2, 20*NUMBER_OF_DATA, 0777|IPC_CREAT);
int shmid2 = shmget(key3, 20*NUMBER_OF_DATA, 0777|IPC_CREAT);

int *a = (int *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
float *b = (float *)(a + NUMBER_OF_DATA);
char **array1 = (char **)shmat(shmid1, 0, 0);
printf("array1 %p\n", &array1);
char *mempos = (char *)(array1 + NUMBER_OF_DATA); 
printf("MEMPOS %p\n", &mempos);
char **array2 = (char **)shmat(shmid2, 0, 0);
char *mempos1 = (char *)(array2 + (NUMBER_OF_DATA)); 
int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("enter\n");

    array1[i] = mempos; 
    scanf("%s", array1[i]);
    mempos += 20;
}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: why are you not using the [boot shared memory library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html)?

Comment: I don't see any error checking in your code whatsoever - how do you even know that all your calls to `shmget`, `shmat`, etc are successful ?

Comment: @drone.ah: it's tagged `c`, so boost is presumably not an option (otherwise I'd agree with you - `boost::interprocess` is the way to go for C++)

Comment: For new code there should be no need to use the complicated `shmget` etc calls. Use the modern POSIX interfaces `shmopen` and `mmap`, instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely *not* what you think it is, but your arrays. An array of arrays is *not* the same thing as a pointer to a pointer.

An array is a contiguous area of memory, and an array of arrays is a contiguous area of contiguous areas, i.e. all of the arrays are following each other. A pointer to a pointer can be seen as an array of pointers, the memory layout is completely different.

Also only the array of pointers are shared but not what the pointers actually point to.

Comment: +1, generally speaken the OP has to learn *a lot* before attempting to write code for shared memory. Already the amount of casts in the code makes me dizzy, good C code usually doesn't need any cast.

Comment: @JensGustedt I hope you know that we always have to case a void* pointer ! that we get from the shared memory address

Comment: @Nidhi: what you say is incorrect for C - it only applies to C++ !